# Glade gui editor for gtk-sharp3

Tags: user-interface, gtk3, gtk#, glade

I followed this official guide: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/

As that tutorial says, my gui.glade is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?> <!--*- mode: xml -*-->
<!DOCTYPE glade-interface SYSTEM "http://glade.gnome.org/glade-2.0.dtd">

<glade-interface>

<widget class="GtkWindow" id="window1">
  <property name="visible">True</property>
  <property name="title" translatable="yes">Glade Window</property>
  <property name="type">GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL</property>
  <property name="window_position">GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER</property>
  <property name="modal">False</property>
  <property name="default_width">256</property>
  <property name="default_height">256</property>
  <property name="resizable">True</property>
  <property name="destroy_with_parent">False</property>
  <property name="decorated">True</property>
  <property name="skip_taskbar_hint">False</property>
  <property name="skip_pager_hint">False</property>
  <property name="type_hint">GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_NORMAL</property>
  <property name="gravity">GDK_GRAVITY_NORTH_WEST</property>
  <property name="focus_on_map">True</property>

  <child>
    <widget class="GtkScrolledWindow" id="scrolledwindow1">
      <property name="visible">True</property>
      <property name="can_focus">True</property>
      <property name="hscrollbar_policy">GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS</property>
      <property name="vscrollbar_policy">GTK_POLICY_ALWAYS</property>
      <property name="shadow_type">GTK_SHADOW_IN</property>
      <property name="window_placement">GTK_CORNER_TOP_LEFT</property>

      <child>
    <widget class="GtkLayout" id="layout1">
      <property name="visible">True</property>
      <property name="width">400</property>
      <property name="height">400</property>
      <property name="hadjustment">0 0 400 10 212.4 236</property>
      <property name="vadjustment">0 0 400 10 212.4 236</property>

      <child>
        <widget class="GtkLabel" id="label1">
          <property name="width_request">38</property>
          <property name="height_request">17</property>
          <property name="visible">True</property>
          <property name="label" translatable="yes">label1</property>
          <property name="use_underline">False</property>
          <property name="use_markup">False</property>
          <property name="justify">GTK_JUSTIFY_LEFT</property>
          <property name="wrap">False</property>
          <property name="selectable">False</property>
          <property name="xalign">0.5</property>
          <property name="yalign">0.5</property>
          <property name="xpad">0</property>
          <property name="ypad">0</property>
          <property name="ellipsize">PANGO_ELLIPSIZE_NONE</property>
          <property name="width_chars">-1</property>
          <property name="single_line_mode">False</property>
          <property name="angle">0</property>
        </widget>
        <packing>
          <property name="x">96</property>
          <property name="y">88</property>
        </packing>
      </child>

      <child>
        <widget class="GtkButton" id="button1">
          <property name="width_request">60</property>
          <property name="height_request">27</property>
          <property name="visible">True</property>
          <property name="can_focus">True</property>
          <property name="label" translatable="yes">button1</property>
          <property name="use_underline">True</property>
          <property name="relief">GTK_RELIEF_NORMAL</property>
          <property name="focus_on_click">True</property>
        </widget>
        <packing>
          <property name="x">88</property>
          <property name="y">168</property>
        </packing>
      </child>
    </widget>
      </child>
    </widget>
  </child>
</widget>

</glade-interface>
```

And compile command:

```
mcs -pkg:glade-sharp-2.0 -resource:gui.glade glade.cs
```

I was happy it works fine. But of course, I don't want to write gui designer code without designer, so I installed Glade editor (version 3.20). But Glade refuses to open above file. I have also noticed syntax generated by Glade is completly different: glade tag instead of glade-interface, object instead of widget etc.

Can you provide some tip where to get gui designer suitable for gtk-sharp3? Also, .glade files generated by Glade are not working with gtk# 3.0.

Comment: You might be needing Glade version 3.8.5, which is the last version that handles 2.0 files (the '.glade' files. More modern versions have their projects normally saved as .ui. They also have a line like '<!-- interface-requires gtk+ 3.10 -->' in them)

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed I'm compiling for gtk2 now. This is weird, because without Glade I'm getting .exe compiled against gtk3. With glade-sharp as above, resulting exe is gtk2. How to compile for gtk3 with glade? I want gtk3, not gtk2. Gtk3 syntax does not work with above compile command.

Comment: The Gtk version you use is determined by the compilation command line. If you are using an IDE (which?) you have to set the library you are linking with in the IDE options. Glade itself cannot change the Gtk version.

Comment: So in this case, layout file generated by Glade is gtk3. But my commandline is gtk2. How to compile for gtk3?

Comment: The layout file in both cases is not related directly to the Gtk version. I believe there are 'backported' versions in the Gtk2 line which can read Glade >3.8.5 files. The issue to compile with Gtk3 depends on how you compile. *How do you compile your C-code?*

Comment: Well, to be specific. Look at my commandline I used to compile. How to modify it to compile for gtk3? Cmmandline I used compiles  for gtk2, this is why I am unable to use layout generated for gtk3 syntax.

Comment: Oh. Ok... It seems there is no Gtk3 version for C# yet. According to http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/plan/, it is planned, but there might be a 2.18 Gtk+ coming out first if not. But even 2.18 seems old - I have 2.24 installed here (native, not c#). It seem you are still bound to Gtk2.

Comment: Hmm, there is gtk3 version for sure. I have installed gtk3 template project for Monodevelop, downloaded gtk-sharp 3.14 from Nuget and now I am able to compile gtk-sharp with gtk3 Glade gui editor. No problems. Also see chapter 4 here: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/ - after compiling as they wrote, I'm getting gtk3 app, not gtk2. However, their Glade sample generates gtk2 executable. I have found mamy gtk-sharp 3 examples, but none of them uses Glade.

Comment: In that case, if the gtk#3 version is compatible, you should be able to compile with `mcs -pkg:glade-sharp-3.0 -resource:gui.glade glade.cs`. I'm just surprised that the official page doesn't mention it. Note that Gtk3 (for C)  does exist for windows and linux, just not sure if it exists for C# (i.e. Gtk#), which is quite different.

Comment: I can't... glade-sharp3 not found, it's not available in debian repo either... but I am able to compile with monodevelop, using 3rd party template for gtk-sharp3. Most important, there is no reference for glade-sharp3

Comment: Well, I guess your main problem is to find your way in the versions available... But one thing: You have no necessity for a glade-sharp3 version. Just Glade 3 should work, as the ui output of Glade is XML, and independent of the C or C# compiler.